# Is it possible to block Facebook's sponsored ads using uBlock now that they separate “sponsored” text onto different divs?

Tags: facebook

If you inspect the word "sponsored" on Facebook's sponsored posts, you'll see they break the word up across multiple elements to bypass uBlock Origin and other blockers. Is there a way to still block Facebook's ads when they do this?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [F.B. Purity](https://www.fbpurity.com) and see if it can do this

Answer (score 0):

Use the following filter:

```
www.facebook.com##.userContentWrapper._5pcr > div:has(.s_v8i43c603)
```

Comment: This won't work because the classes change.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Sadly no option for mobile app.

> facebook.com##:xpath(//div[starts-with(@id, 'pagelet') and
> (.//a[.='Sponsored'])]  ) facebook.com###pagelet_ego_pane
> facebook.com###pagelet_video_home_watch_list_rhc
> facebook.com##div[id^=hyperfeed_story_id_] .userContentWrapper
> div:has-text(/Suggested Events|Suggested for You/)
> facebook.com##.userContentWrapper:if(span:matches-css-after(content:
> "Suggested post";))
> facebook.com###pagelet_marketplace_recently_viewed_rhc
> facebook.com###pagelet_ego_contextual_group
> facebook.com##div[data-pagelet^="FeedUnit"]:has-text(/Suggested
> Events|Suggested for You/)
> facebook.com##div[data-pagelet="FeedUnit_{n}"]:has-text(/Suggested
> Events|Suggested for You/)
> facebook.com##div[data-pagelet^="FeedUnit_"]:has(a[aria-label="Sponsored"])
> facebook.com##div[data-pagelet^="FeedUnit"]:has(span:has-text(/Sponsored/):not(:has-text(/1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|w/)))